# File Scanner scanner not scanning all information properly

Tags: java, file, object, text

I have a File Scanner Class , that is, for reading names from a customer list (I also have another file ,that is , being used to read into the `Customer` objects, but those are being reading fine). My list looks like this (I just skip past the number and then read the name into the String `name`):

1,Bobby

2,Joe

3,Sue

4,Mary

5,Victor

But for some reason, when I print out with the toString(), **the only name that is showing up is Victor.** I want each `customer` object to have its own respective name.

**Question: How can I get the `lineScanner` to properly read in all five names and then have them show up in the toString()?**

```
//reads in customer name info
File customerList = new File("./src/Customers.txt");
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(customerList);

//while there is a new line, goes to next one
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");

    //while there is a new attribute to read in on a given line, reads data
    while(lineScanner.hasNext())
    {
        lineScanner.next();
        name = lineScanner.next();
        customer1 = new Customer(ranking, name, tvTimeTotal1, exerciseTimeTotal1);
        customer2 = new Customer(ranking, name, tvTimeTotal2, exerciseTimeTotal2);
        customer3 = new Customer(ranking, name, tvTimeTotal3, exerciseTimeTotal3);
        customer4 = new Customer(ranking, name, tvTimeTotal4, exerciseTimeTotal4);
        customer5 = new Customer(ranking, name, tvTimeTotal5, exerciseTimeTotal5);
    }
}


System.out.println(customer1.toString());
System.out.println(customer2.toString());
System.out.println(customer3.toString());
System.out.println(customer4.toString());
System.out.println(customer5.toString());
```

Comment: You get a single name with `name = lineScanner.next();` then create 5 Customers with that data. You should only create 1 customer per loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
File customerList = new File("./src/Customers.txt");
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(customerList);

List<String> customerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
    lineScanner.next(); // Discard number
    customerNames.add(lineScanner.next());
}

for(String name : customerNames)
{
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Worked out great!

Answer (score 0):

You sre actually writting same data on each Customer object in each of the iterations i.e. you are writing Bobby on all objects in first iteration and so on. So ultimately you are left with Victor on all object after the loop. Try using an array or an `ArrayList` instead of this approach. See the one suggested by @BertieWheen. If you are a beginner than I would suggest you to use an array.

```
int i=0;
while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
  lineScanner.next();
  name = lineScanner.next();
  customer[i++] = new Customer(ranking, name, tvTimeTotal1, exerciseTimeTotal1);
}
```

or if you are comfortable with `ArrayList`

```
List customer=new ArrayList<Customer>();

while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
  lineScanner.next();
  name = lineScanner.next();
  customer.add(new Customer(ranking, name, tvTimeTotal1, exerciseTimeTotal1));
}
```